# is there a way to import API data from one file to another one in React?

Tags: reactjs, api, redirect, react-props

So I'm working on this app that as soon as you search up a shoe brand it takes you to a page that gives you a grid of the different types of shoes that brand has.

This is the API search bar function that's located in the searchBar.js file:

```
function SearchBar() {

  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState("");
  const [sneakers, setSneakers] = useState({});
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)

  const brandsList = [
    { brandName: "Adidas" },
    { brandName: "Asics" },
    { brandName: "Converse" },
    { brandName: "Jordan" },
    { brandName: "New Balance" },
    { brandName: "Nike" },
    { brandName: "Puma" },
    { brandName: "Reebok" },
    { brandName: "Saucony" },
    { brandName: "Under Armour" },
    { brandName: "Vans" }
  ]
  const defaultBrands = {
    options: brandsList,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.brandName,
  };


  const search = (evt) => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(
        `https://api.thesneakerdatabase.com/v1/sneakers?limit=10&brand=${brand}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setBrand("");
          setSneakers(result);
          console.log(result.results);
          setRedirect(true)
        });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {
          redirect ? <Redirect to="/allShoes:id" /> : <div className="brand-search">
            <div className="search-box col">
              <Autocomplete
                {...defaultBrands}
                id="auto-complete"
                autoComplete
                includeInputInList
                renderInput={(params) =>
                  <TextField {...params}
                    placeholder="Search brand..."
                    margin="normal"
                    onChange={(e) => setBrand(e.target.value)}
                    value={brand}
                    onKeyPress={search}
                  />}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

and I'm trying to the api data into the allShoes.js file once you search a brand:

```
import React from "react";
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBCard, MDBCardImage, MDBCardBody, MDBCardTitle, MDBCardFooter, MDBCardText } from "mdbreact";
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import NotesIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notes';

import "../allShoes/allShoes.css";


function gridTable(props) {

return (
    
    <div>
    
    <MDBContainer style={{textAlign:"center", marginTop:"8%"}}>
        
        <h2>View All Shoes</h2>

        <MDBRow style={{padding: "6%"}}>
            <MDBCol size="3">
            <MDBCard narrow ecommerce className='mb-2'>
            <MDBCardTitle>
                      <strong>
                      {/* {name} */}
                      </strong>
                    </MDBCardTitle>
                    <MDBCardImage
                    cascade
                    top
                    src='https://static.nike.com/a/images/f_auto/q_auto:eco/t_PDP_864_v1/eric5lwitzffpoisq0rj/blazer-mid-77-vintage-mens-shoe-flCCX4.jpg'
                    alt='shoe photo'
                  />
                  <MDBCardBody cascade>
                    <MDBCardFooter className='px-1'>
                      <span className='float-left'>
                      {/* {title} */}
                      </span>
                      <span className='float-right'>
                       <FavoriteIcon></FavoriteIcon>
                        <NotesIcon></NotesIcon>
                      </span>
                    </MDBCardFooter>
                  </MDBCardBody>
                </MDBCard>
            </MDBCol>
        </MDBRow>
    </MDBContainer>


    </div>
);
}

export default gridTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to move the shoes data and the setter function to set the shoesData outside `SearchBar`. Preferably using the `ContextAPI`, share it downstream - so as to make these available to all the components including the `gridTable`.

Additionally, while redirecting you can pass the brand-id in the url to filter out other brands in the `allBrands` page.